# Help with set theory proof.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i am trying to prove
$
(\bigcup_\ S) \times (\bigcup_\ T) \subset (\bigcup_\ \{ X \times Y | X \in S, Y \in T\})
$.
And this seems straight forward, but for some reason i have a hard time applying the definitions without getting confused. 
I start by 
$
(u,v) \in (\bigcup_\ S) \times (\bigcup_\ T);
\space u \in \bigcup_\ S \space and \space v \in \bigcup_\ T \\
So \space u \in X, \space X \in S \space and \space v \in Y, Y \in T \\
(u,v) \in \{(x,y) | x \in X, y \in Y, X \in S, Y \in T\} \\
(u,v) \in \{(x,y) \in X \times Y |X \in S, Y \in T\} 
$.

I am really not sure if this is even correct usage of the definition, i am really confused at this. Is there any method i should consider to keep the definitions straight and apply them correctly? If i understand correctly i want to arrive at something that looks like this.

$
(u,v) \in \{(x,y)| (x,y) \in A, A \in X \times Y\}
$

Comment: I don't see why you have the union signs. You just have one set $S$, and one set $T$, and its cross product. Are you taking the union of multiple sets $S_i$ for $i\in\mathcal{I}$ for some index set $\mathcal{I}$?

Comment: This is how the question was stated in a book I am self learning. S and T are sets who's element are sets. Atleast I think that is implied in the problem. To clarify the union in the example means the union of all elements that are also sets.

Comment: So by $\cup S$, it means $\cup_{X\in S}X$? That makes sense, though it would be helpful if you included it in the original post to be clear.

Comment: Sorry I thought it was implied, atleast it is this notation the book uses. But yes I will be more careful in the future. Now about the proof, am I inntge right track, where did my thinking go wrong. I honestly am having trouble to apply the definitions correctly, it's a mess, And I would love some help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it would help to rewrite the problem; the exercise uses a more concise notation to denote the union of all sets in a collection, but that obscures what each of the summands (uniands?) in the union looks like. You can write this more clearly as

$(\bigcup_{X\in S}X)\times (\bigcup_{Y\in T}Y)\subseteq \bigcup_{X\in S, Y\in T}X\times Y$.

Then, as you say, if $(u,v)$ is a term in the set on the left hand side, then $u\in X_0$ for some $X_0\in S$, and $v\in Y_0$ for some $Y_0\in T$. Then you must have $(u,v)\in X_0\times Y_0$, so it's in the set on the right hand side. Your argument is correct, but it can be useful to see exactly what the union being taken is.

Comment: Thank you, yes your notation is much clearer, maybe this is why the book used this notation so one would be forced to rewrite it like you did